# Autocomplete Material show [object object]

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

Autocomplete material implementation, but selecting an item from the list shows as [object object].

To show the array of data in which it requires the use of this module I apply it with the following view.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="item">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="itemDataChange($event)" 
      [displayFn]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of itemsListFiltrado | async" [value]="option.value"> 
      {{option.option}}</mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

I need to use the value property of the selected item, but instead I want to show its option. These properties conform to the interface applied in the controller.

I apply filtering on the array *itemsList* using this process:

```
export interface Option {
  option: string;
  value: string;
}

// (...)


public itemsList: Option[] = [];
public itemsListFiltrado: Observable<Option[]>;
public codigoArticuloInsrt: number;

filterItems(option: any) {
  const filterValue = option.toString().toLowerCase();
      const filterList = this.itemsList.filter(indexArt => 
        indexArt.option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
      if (filterList.length === 1) {
        // property used for data saving
        // for saving the form for saving the form
        this.codigoItemInsrt = parseInt(filterList[0].value, 0);
      }
      return filterList;
   }
listFltr() {
  return this.itemsListFiltrado =

    // when the controller changes value 
    this.editDetailLineForm.controls.item.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(param => this.filterItems(param))
      );
  }
```

Finally, it is instantiated in the method that calls the service that loads the data into the array.

In the old thread found in [Github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/6108) I use the displayWith attribute, but I don't get any kind of change.

```
displayFn(i: Option) {
    if (i) { return i.option; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your method being called? Try writing to the console inside the function to verify. You may need to make `displayFn` an arrow function, as in:

```
displayFn = (i: Option) => {
  console.log('in displayFn, param = ', i);
  if (i) {
    console.log('returning i.option', i.option);
    return i.option;
  } else {
    console.log('no Option');
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

If, after all of that, your method *is* being called, and nothing else is obvious, 
is `i.option` a string, or an object?

Comment: `i.option` is a string. The object is composed of option and value.